# How to display a post's title through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Very new to Rails and programming.

I have the following associations:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts
has_many :comments
```

And in my user#show view I want to create a table that has columns for Commented On, and a Link. And I want the Commented On column to be the name of the post the user commented on.

My comments table has post_id and a user_id foreign keys that get populated upon generation of the comment. I'm struggling to figure out how to retrieve the post title based on the post_id

I want to do something like the following:

```
<% @user.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= comment.post_id.title %></td>
        <td>|</td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(comment.post_id) %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

The "comment.post_id.title" is not embedding the title of the post in the view.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<% @user.comments.includes(:post).each do |comment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comment.post.title %></td>
    <td>|</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(comment.post) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh thank god that works lol. I've been trying to figure it out for hours now. I'm going to look for more documentation on the include method. But if you happen to know where it is, could you link it?

Comment: @RyanOliverLanham Read more about the `includes` method in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). Please note that `includes` is just an optimization. The real issue was that your tried to call `comment.post_id.title` instead of `comment.post.title`.

Comment: Okay, so I think I have a better understanding of what's going on now. Is `comment.post.title` basically an association within an association? Like `@user.comments.post.title`? Because users have many comments, and comments belong to one post, which has a title?

Comment: `comment` is your model, `post` load the associated post and `title` calls the  title attribute in that post. This works because `comment.post` returns one post. Whereas `users.comments.post` would not work, because `users.comments` returns an array of comments and you cannot call `title` directly on that array. You would need something like `users.comments.map { |comment| comment.post.title }` in that case.